# How to call android NFC API to get UID using Python

Tags: android, nfc, qpython

Hi I am working on Nexus 7 Tab and I have installed Qpython and able to Scan Barcode with below code`import androidhelper
d = androidhelper.Android()
d.scanBarcode()`when i run this in Qpython consol I am getting the barcode ID same way iam able to connect,check the status of Bluetooth device, WIFI etc...
But iam not able find

- How have control to ON/OFF the NFC device.
- How to know the NFC connection status.
- How to get the TagID when card flashed.

please help me I am trying this from so many days.

Comment: Give some Ideas please

Answer (score 0):

QPython's newest version 0.9.6.x has support NFC Message Beam, You can get sample scripts from http://packages.qpython.org/index.php/qpython-sl4a/, But you should enable/disable the NFC device manually.